# Are multiple updates of a Chrome extension applied incrementally?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I rely on 1.0.0 *always* being followed by 1.0.1, or should I also expect 1.0.2 if the user has not received 1.0.1 yet but 1.0.2 is the latest?

Basically, can 1.0.0->1.0.2 happen? Excluding 1.0.1.

The problem is, I have data structures that may change between versions and I want to figure out how to best migrate the data between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience no, you should write code that expects 1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 excluding 1.0.1

Chrome will update to the latest version of Chrome extension it can find.

Comment: Thanks. Have you any experience with managing data structures in an extension between different versions? I'm afraid that the extension may bloat up trying to migrate data from all the previous versions to the new data structure. Assuming there are significant changes between versions.

Comment: @ikaruss That is whole another topic of fun. But I generally version the objects of the data structures i.e PersonV1,PersonV2 and then check against what I have locally and run a migrate code to move from X to Y version. i.e I store DataStructure=1. But it will depend on your needs and demands. You might be able to avoid all of this by storing data and structures server side and calling them in from a webservices. Then you are just version against webservice.

Comment: That's exactly what I was afraid of. I might end up mimicking 1.0.0->1.0.1->1.0.2 with separate migration scripts for every version pair in the chain. Seems like the most sane way at first glance. Thanks again.